# ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell - in tensorflow while loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

System information

```
Linux Ubuntu 16.04
tensorflow-gpu==1.1.0
```

I am getting this error in quite a complex graph, but I can reproduce it with a minimal (but hopefully representative) example below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, batch_size, input_size):

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.input_size = input_size

        with tf.name_scope("controller"):
            self.network_vars()

            self.nn_output_size = None
            with tf.variable_scope("shape_inference"):
                self.nn_output_size = self.get_nn_output_size()

    def network_vars(self):
        self.lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(256)
        self.state = self.lstm_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)

    def network_op(self, x, state):
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
        return self.lstm_cell(x, state)

    def get_state(self):
        return self.state

    def update_state(self, new_state):
        return tf.no_op()

    def process_input(self, x, state=None):
        nn_output, nn_state = self.network_op(x, state)
        return nn_output, nn_state

    def get_nn_output_size(self):
        input_tensor = np.zeros([self.batch_size, self.input_size], dtype=np.float32)
        output_vector, _ = self.network_op(input_tensor, self.get_state())
        shape = output_vector.get_shape().as_list()

        if len(shape) > 2:
            raise ValueError("Expected the neural network to output a 1D vector")
        else:
            return shape[1]


class DNC(object):
    def __init__(self, controller, batch_size, input_size):
        self.controller = controller
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.build_graph()

    def _step_op(self, x, controller_state=None):
        _, nn_state = self.controller.process_input(x, controller_state)
        return [nn_state[0], nn_state[1]]

    def _loop_body(self, t, controller_state):
        x = np.random.random_sample((self.batch_size, self.input_size)).astype(np.float32)
        output_list = self._step_op(x, controller_state)
        new_controller_state = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(output_list[0], output_list[1])
        return t+1, new_controller_state

    def build_graph(self):
        controller_state = self.controller.get_state()
        if not isinstance(controller_state, tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple):
            controller_state = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(controller_state[0], controller_state[1])

        with tf.variable_scope("sequence_loop") as scope:
            time = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)

            final_results = tf.while_loop(
                cond=lambda time, *_: time < 50,
                body=self._loop_body,
                loop_vars=(time, controller_state),
                parallel_iterations=32,
                swap_memory=True
            )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    batch_size = 32
    input_size = 10
    rnn_controller = Controller(batch_size, input_size)
    dnc = DNC(rnn_controller, batch_size, input_size)
```

The traceback of the issue is:

```
francescoferroni@francescoferroni:~$ python controller.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 84, in <module>
    dnc = DNC(rnn_controller, batch_size, input_size)
  File "controller.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "controller.py", line 77, in build_graph
    swap_memory=True
  File "/home/francescoferroni/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2623, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/francescoferroni/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2456, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/francescoferroni/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2406, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "controller.py", line 60, in _loop_body
    output_list = self._step_op(x, controller_state)
  File "controller.py", line 55, in _step_op
    _, nn_state = self.controller.process_input(x, controller_state)
  File "controller.py", line 33, in process_input
    nn_output, nn_state = self.network_op(x, state)
  File "controller.py", line 24, in network_op
    return self.lstm_cell(x, state)
  File "/home/francescoferroni/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 235, in __call__
    with _checked_scope(self, scope or "basic_lstm_cell", reuse=self._reuse):
  File "/home/francescoferroni/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/francescoferroni/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 77, in _checked_scope
    type(cell).__name__))
ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell <tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn_cell_impl.BasicLSTMCell object at 0x7fcaeca99518> with a different variable scope than its first use.  First use of cell was with scope 'shape_inference/basic_lstm_cell', this attempt is with scope 'sequence_loop/basic_lstm_cell'.  Please create a new instance of the cell if you would like it to use a different set of weights.  If before you were using: MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...)] * num_layers), change to: MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...) for _ in range(num_layers)]).  If before you were using the same cell instance as both the forward and reverse cell of a bidirectional RNN, simply create two instances (one for forward, one for reverse).  In May 2017, we will start transitioning this cell's behavior to use existing stored weights, if any, when it is called with scope=None (which can lead to silent model degradation, so this error will remain until then.)
```

If I use tensorflow 1.0 rather than 1.1 it causes no issues.

```
francescoferroni@francescoferroni:~$ source Repositories/tfr10/bin/activate
(tfr10) francescoferroni@francescoferroni:~$ python controller.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
(tfr10) francescoferroni@francescoferroni:~$
```

For the new tensorflow version, I have tried to add a reuse=True flag, when defining the LSTM cell, but then I get another error:

```
ValueError: Variable shape_inference/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

I also tried removing the scope in the controller definition.

```
ValueError: Variable basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

I suspect it is something to do with the while loop in build_graph(). I tried following other answers but could not get it to work with this tensorflow while loop case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Any Tensorflow wizards know the answer?

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [tf.make_template](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_template), a wrapper around variable creation which keeps the identity of referenced TensorFlow variables bound to the Python template object. Modifying your example, I renamed `Controller.network_op` to `Controller._network_op_impl`, then in `Controller.__init__` added (doesn't matter much where as long as it's before `network_op` is called):

```
self.network_op = tf.make_template("network_op", self._network_op_impl)
```